# Getting black and white image after applying mask

Tags: swift, image-processing

I am removing background from image containing at least one human body. I am applying mask to UIImage and successfully masked image containing only human body with transparent background, but if I tried to convert to UIImage back after applying mask I am getting black and white cropped image.

I am using this snippet to apply mask and get result as UIImage

```swift
func maskImage(image:UIImage, mask:(UIImage))->UIImage{

        let imageReference = image.cgImage
        let maskReference = mask.cgImage

        let imageMask = CGImage(maskWidth: maskReference!.width,
                                height: maskReference!.height,
                                bitsPerComponent: maskReference!.bitsPerComponent,
                                bitsPerPixel: maskReference!.bitsPerPixel,
                                bytesPerRow: maskReference!.bytesPerRow,
                                provider: maskReference!.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)

        let maskedReference = imageReference!.masking(imageMask!)

        let maskedImage = UIImage(cgImage:maskedReference!)

        return maskedImage
    }
```

but I am getting black and white image with only human body instead of coloured.

Answer (score 0):

After doing much research I finally got answer as below:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgView1.frame.size, _: false, _: 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: (imgView1?.frame.size.height)!)
    context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    let maskImage = maskImg.cgImage
    context?.clip(to: imgView1!.bounds, mask: maskImage!)
    context?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: (imgView1?.frame.size.height)!)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context?.stroke(imgView1!.frame, width: 15.0)
    context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    imgView1?.image?.draw(in: imgView1?.bounds ?? CGRect.zero)

    let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```